# HTML error message on button text

Tags: javascript, html

The following HTML code is throwing error message.

```
<button name="btnSave" id="btnSave" onclick="/chbs/adm/HallNamesValidation.jsp" 
    class="btn btn-success">Save to Database</button>
```

The error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
```

I am attempting to invoke `HallNamesValidation.jsp` without using `<form action="">` because there are other `<button>`s on the page.

I have managed to get it working using AJAX as follows, but I'd like to know how I can make this work using my original method because with Ajax I need to add data which is an array to be processed with `jsp getParameterValues()`:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function() { 
  $.ajax({ 
    url: '/chbs/adm/HallNamesValidation.jsp', 
    success: function (data) { console.log(data); } 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Post the code causing the error?

Comment: Did it in original post

Comment: Got Success with workaround using ajax call but will await if there is better solution. The code is `  $('#btnSave').click(function() { ///Saving Table Data to MySQL through Ajax Call
 $.ajax({
     url: '/chbs/adm/HallNamesValidation.jsp',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
  });`

Comment: Hi @Raky, I've updated your question with your code. If you have more to add, please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48503981/edit) link on your post instead of the comments.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, Thanks sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onclick` expects some javascript code, so `/chbs/adm/HallNamesValidation.jsp` is converted as a regular expression

what you might want to do is

```
onclick="location.href='/chbs/adm/HallNamesValidation.jsp'"
```